# error in calling oracle jdbc in axis2 web service

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-axis

I have problem in making axis web service which has java class java to make (oracle jdbc)

```
    package com.omar;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DB {
    public Connection connectDB(Connection conn){
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!"); 
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/orcl.world", "omar",
                    "a1s2w3e4r5t6");
        //  statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        //  System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

i tried the deployment using the eclipse 
and this is the errors

```
Error: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: null
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:432)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:178)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.loadServices(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:283)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5317)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: null
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:396)
    ... 27 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchemaforFieldsandProperties(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:732)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:623)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchemaforFieldsandProperties(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:732)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:623)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchemaforFieldsandProperties(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:732)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:623)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchemaTypeforNameCommon(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:1092)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchemaForType(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:996)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.processMethods(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:385)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:273)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:468)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:388)
    ... 27 more
```